# foreach statement not checking all conditions

Tags: php, foreach

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying to check that no field is empty in a certain form, so I used a `foreach` statement but it only checks one by one instead of all at once.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST[submit])) {
    ValidateUser();
}

function ValidateUser() {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $details = array($username, $password);

    foreach($details as $detail) {
        if (!empty($detail)) {
            echo "hurrayy";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

So instead of displaying "hurrayy" when BOTH username and password are not empty, it displays as long as one of them is not empty. Please help.

Comment: And when both are non-empty, it displays "hurrayy" twice? If PHP is like languages I *do* know, it will loop through all items one-by-one. Just check both values.

Comment: Line `$username = $_POST['username'];` will throw error if there is no `username` key in `POST`. Also, if using checkboxes and non is selected, there will be no entry in `POST` of checkboxes

Comment: @hans yes it displays "hurrayy" twice if both are not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assign them to an array and loop

```
function ValidateUser() {
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) AND !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    echo "Hurray!";
    }
}
```

8 lines down to 5, no loop and no array assignment.

Comment: thank you but i wanted to know how to do it with a foreach loop but i'll keep this in mind as well. Thanks!

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but I would just recommend in the scenario you're providing (a login system) that it's not really needed, but fair enough. Nothing wrong with learning something new!

Comment: actually i ended up using your method.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `break` after the message has been echo'ed once. It will stop the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($details as $detail) {
    if (!empty($detail)) {
        echo "hurrayy";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display "hurrayy" only if *none* of the fields in the array are empty? You need to check them all first and then decide.

```
function ValidateUser() {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $details = array($username, $password);

  $empty_field = false;

  foreach($details as $detail) {
    if (empty($detail)) {
        $empty_field = true;
    }
  }

  if (!$empty_field)
    echo "hurrayy";
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far. I know this is a dumb question but why does $empty_field have both true and false values?

Comment: It's setting it to false to begin with because it hasn't found any empty fields yet. Then it checks each detail in the `foreach` and if any one of them are empty it sets it to true. If that didn't happen then none of the fields are empty so it will still be false and echo "hurrayy"

Answer (score 0):

yes it will enter the if statement because `$username` and `$password` is considered as value in the array even if those two doesn't have a value.